# Windows Server Desktop experiencie version 1803 google cloud

Tags: 3d, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nvidia, windows-server

I have created a new instance in google cloud with windows server 2016 desktop experiencie. But this version have the 1607 of windows. We want to use the new Raytracing inside of gcloud VM with nvidia but for this we need the 1803.

Anyone know if we can update to this version? I have readed that 1803 don't have the desktop experiencie.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

The Windows server 1803 only has a core version and don't have a desktop version. You cannot upgrade the version to 1803, you have to clean install it instead. GCP has the Windows 1803 core version available. You can find this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/get-started-with-1803) for more information and you can post your question to Windows [forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home).